# Нужно прибавить все значения из словаря

Tags: python, парсер, функции

У меня имеется код для парсинга, выглядит он так:

```
Roman = {
        'I' : 1,
        'II': 2,
        'III':3,
        'V' : 5,
        'X' : 10,
        'L': 50,
        'C' : 100,
        'D' : 500,
        'M' : 1000
         }
def RomantoArabic(number):

      if len(number) == 1:
            print (Roman[number])

      elif len(number) == 2:
            if Roman[number[0]] < Roman[number[1]]:
               print (Roman[number[1]] - Roman[number[0]])
            if Roman[number[0]] >= Roman[number[1]]:
               print(Roman[number[1]] + Roman[number[0]])

      elif len(number) > 2 and Roman[number[0]] >= Roman[number[1]] and not Roman[number[-1]] > Roman[number[-2]]:
            Arabic = sum(Roman[blabla] for blabla in number)
            print(Arabic)
      elif len(number) > 2 and Roman[number[0]] <= Roman[number[1]] and not Roman[number[-1]] > Roman[number[-2]]:
            Arabic = (Roman[number[1]] - Roman[number[0]]) #Тут надо прибавить все оставшиеся числа
            print(Arabic)
```

В самой последней строке, где Arabic, я уже минусую число с первого индекса от
второго, однако, в резуьтате я должен получить общую сумму и я не знаю как мне прибавить все оставшиеся числа (которые должны браться из словаря, поскольку у меня приходят римские буквы на вход) Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно запоминать предыдущий символ и убирать его, если он меньше текущего

```
def RomantoArabic(number):
    res = 0
    prev = 2000
    for num in number:
        if Roman[num] > prev:
            res += - 2*prev
        res += Roman[num]
        prev = Roman[num]
    print(res)
```